# Why is Chrome loading smallest srcset image on DPR 1.5 displays?

Tags: image, google-chrome, webkit, srcset, blink

Chrome load an unexpected image (400w) from srcset when the display is 1.5 DPR, sizes is set to 580px and a bigger image is available in the srcset (1893w). Cannot reproduce this error with any other DPR or any not WebKit browser. If the big image is smaller then 1893 it works fine.

```
<img 
    sizes="580px" 
    srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/1893 1893w, https://via.placeholder.com/400 400w" 
    src="https://via.placeholder.com/100">    
<img 
    sizes="580px" 
    srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/1892 1892w, https://via.placeholder.com/400 400w" 
    src="https://via.placeholder.com/100">
```

https://cdpn.io/AndreuGenestar/debug/ExaZXPm/gakeYzBDmBLk

Is it an issue in Blink or am I missing something?